# レビューキュー画面にて未ログイン状態で表示される文字列が翻訳できない

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

「初めての質問」等のレビューキュー画面に "未ログイン" の状態でアクセスすると、ログインを促すメッセージが表示されますが、この文字列が traducir で見つからず翻訳できません。

そもそも未ログインだとトップページからはこれらのページにアクセスする導線が無いので優先度は低いかもしれませんが、私自身がこれらのページを開いたタイミングで急にログインセッションが切れたことで気づきました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: traducir で検索すると、それらしき翻訳文字列が有ります。
マークアップが有りそうな場所には `.*` を入れるなど、適当な正規表現を使うとマッチしやすいです。
[`Please.*log in.*to review`](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Please.*log%20in.*to%20review)

Comment: @mjy さん、@cubick さん、ありがとうございます！https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15821 と https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15812  だと思いますので翻訳案を入力いたしました。反映まで数日お待ちくださいませ‍♀️。

Comment: @mjy 自分が確認したタイミングでは単純に `^Please` でも出てこなかった気がしたのですが、文字列があるなら大きな問題は無さそうですね。(aki さんもありがとうございます)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の通り、翻訳が反映されたのを確認しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]